# How to remove object element that match from an array using splice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

here is my data of array1 :

`[ { members: [ '60ee9148104cc81bec3b97ab' ] } ]`

and here is array2:

`[{"_id": "60ee9148104cc81bec3b97ab","username": "user1", "email": "user1@gmail.com"}, {"_id": "60ee917f767bd11d687326c7","username": "user2","email": "user2@gmail.com"}]`

and I want to remove the object from my array2 which _id is equal to `60ee9148104cc81bec3b97ab`

I have tried so far as

```
    let user = await User.find({ _id: { $ne: req.user._id } })

        const getNonfriends = (one) => {
            user.splice(user.indexOf(one.members[0]), 1)
           //user.filter(entry => entry._id !== one.members[0])
        }

   array1.map(getNonfriends)
```

filter or splice non of them bring my solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answers, I got the clue and this brings my desire results. here is one thing that array1 can have multiple elements so it needs to be mapped over with invoking the getNonfriends finction.
so,

```
let user = await User.find({ _id: { $ne: req.user._id } })
const getNonfriends = (one) => {
           user = user.filter(item => !one.members.includes(item._id))
           return user;
        }
await array1.map(getNonfriends)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Array.prototype.filter()
I think there is no need to find the index of the array and slice.
Also, we can use the Array.prototype.map, it is similar to use the filter function

```js
const obj1 = [{
  members: ['60ee9148104cc81bec3b97ab']
}]
const obj2 = [{
  "_id": "60ee9148104cc81bec3b97ab",
  "username": "user1",
  "email": "user1@gmail.com"
}, {
  "_id": "60ee917f767bd11d687326c7",
  "username": "user2",
  "email": "user2@gmail.com"
}]
const getAnswer = (obj2) => {
  const res = obj2.filter(item => !obj1[0].members.includes(item._id))
  return res;
}
console.log(getAnswer(obj2));
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. It's probably a *better* way to do it than the OP was asking for, but that requires explanation as to why you prefer it to the solution requested.

Comment: here obj1  can have multiple elements and it needs to be mapped over and invoked the getAnswer  function,  the clue from your answare i got my desier results by modifing as :   const getAnswer = ( one ) => {
           obj2 = obj2 .filter( item => !one.members.includes( item._id ));
            return user;
        }
        await obj1.map( getAnswer  );

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you make is that you have *similar* objects, yet you search for identical objects.

```
var array1 = [ { members: [ '60ee9148104cc81bec3b97ab' ] } ];
var array2 = [{"_id": "60ee9148104cc81bec3b97ab","username": "user1", "email": "user1@gmail.com"}, {"_id": "60ee917f767bd11d687326c7","username": "user2","email": "user2@gmail.com"}]

    for (var x of array1) {
        for (var member of x.members) {
            var objects = array2.filter(item => item._id === member)
            for (var obj of objects) array2.splice(array2.indexOf(obj), 1)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with IDs, I am going to assume that the second array *cannot* contain two items with the same ID.
If that assumption is correct, you could do:

```js
const data = [{
  "_id": "60ee9148104cc81bec3b97ab",
  "username": "user1",
  "email": "user1@gmail.com"
}, {
  "_id": "60ee917f767bd11d687326c7",
  "username": "user2",
  "email": "user2@gmail.com"
}];

const filter = [{
  members: ['60ee9148104cc81bec3b97ab']
}];

// SOLUTION 1: using Array.prototype.findIndex() and Array.prototype.splice()
const filteredDataA = [...data] // as splice() modifies the original array, I think it is safer to work on a copy of the original data
filter[0].members.forEach(id => {
  const index = filteredDataA.findIndex(item => item._id === id); // find the index of the item with the same ID
  if (index > -1) filteredDataA.splice(index, 1); // (if found) remove the item
})
console.log('SOLUTION 1: using Array.prototype.findIndex() and Array.prototype.splice()');
console.log(filteredDataA);
console.log('--------------------');

// SOLUTION 2: using array.prototype.filter() and array.prototype.includes()
const filteredDataB = data.filter(item => !filter[0].members.includes(item._id));
console.log('SOLUTION 2: using array.prototype.filter() and array.prototype.includes()');
console.log(filteredDataB);
console.log('--------------------');
```

I'd prefer "Solution 2" as I think is more readable